# How to split python work between cores? (Multiprocessing lib)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a sequential function that sorts through lists and performs tasks. For example... (this is not the actual code but is analagous)

```
def myFunction(list):
   for item in list:
      sublist_a=item[0]
      sublist_b=item[1]
      sublist_c=item[2]
      sublist_d=item[3]
   for row in sublist_a:
      #(do tasks....)
   for row in sublist_b:
      #(do tasks....)
   for row in sublist_c:
      #(do tasks....)
   for row in sublist_d:
      #(do tasks....)
   print "COMPLETE"
```

So this is overly simplified, but essentially these lists are quire large, and the order of execution is important (ie. `for row in ....`), so I would like to split them between the available cores on my system.

Could someone please suggest a method for doing so?

Have never used the Multiprocessing library but it seems this is probably the best to use with python.

Comment: "the order of execution is important", as in "needs to be done sequentially", as in "cannot be split between cores"?

Comment: some of the work can be split - for example, I think you could split the work for each of the `for` loops. But the loops would need to be executed one after the other.

Comment: @sidewaiise What are you doing to each `row`? It seems that's the only piece that can actually be parallelized, right?

Comment: @dano Yes this is true. Each loop simply cleans the list data in different ways. how do I parallelize it though? do I need to turn each of these loops into functions that utilize the `multiprocessing` lib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def function_to_process_a(row):
    return row * 42 # or something similar

# replace 4 by the number of cores that you want to utilize
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    # The lists are processed one after another,
    # but the items are processed in parallel.
    processed_sublist_a = pool.map(function_to_process_a, sublist_a)
    processed_sublist_b = pool.map(function_to_process_b, sublist_b)
    processed_sublist_c = pool.map(function_to_process_c, sublist_c)
    processed_sublist_d = pool.map(function_to_process_d, sublist_d)
```

Edit: As sidewaiise pointed out in the comments, it is preferable to use this pattern:

```
from contextlib import closing, cpu_count, Pool

with closing(Pool(processes=cpu_count())) as pool
    pass # do something
```

Comment: Actually Kay, Just to confirm, is sublist_a, sublist_b etc. inputs? Eg. similar to calling a `function_to_process_a(sublist_a)`?

Comment: `sublist_a` should be iterable. `function_to_process_a` gets a single row as argument, just like the ordinary [`map(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: Ok great. Now I get `AttributeError: __exit__`. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Actually i tried replacing the `with Pool(processes=2) as pool` statement with `pool = Pool(processes=2)` and the error was different:

`PROCESSORS: 2
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File ".../2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`

Comment: You have to use `with Pool(…) as …:`

Comment: yes but I receive the `AttributeError: __exit__` if I use that.

Comment: From your error message I guess that the elements in the sublists are not [pickle-able](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Are you working with database rows, that use proxies? For `pool.map()` you should only provide base types as argument (dict, list, tuple, str, bytes, int).

Comment: im using lists [] as the sublists. There are some nested lists though, for example `[var1, [str_a,str_b,str_c,...]]` the rows in these lists typically come from CSV. I was trying a csv_reader object but converted it to a list also. Error still occurs.

Comment: Also... (thanks for helping on this one) -> my functions do not return anything. They simply write to log files at the end and return None. Is this a problem for using pool.map?

Comment: had to use `from contextlib import closing`, then `while closing(Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())) as pool`. Thanks, your answer basically answered the question.

Comment: I never realized that one should close the Pool manually. Thanks, now we have taught each other. :)