# How to split processing of 52 (processing-independent) stream event types between 4 cores in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I am processing the following stream:

```
symbols = ['ABC', 'DFG', ... (52 of these)]

handlers = { symbol: Handler(symbol) for symbol in symbols }

for symbol, payload in lines:
    handlers[symbol].feed(payload)
```

I would like to split the work between the 4 CPU cores on my MacBookPro (as I have 600M lines to process).

Each handler is independent of the others. However it contains state, so I couldn't have CPU1 process 'ABC' and then CPU2 process 'ABC', or they might clash.

I imagine I need to use `multiprocessing.Pool`, something like this: [How to split python work between cores? (Multiprocessing lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966039/how-to-split-python-work-between-cores-multiprocessing-lib)

I'm thinking I could do `core_index = symbols.index(symbol) % 4`, and then something like `core[core_index].execute_function(process_line(symbol, payload))` but it isn't that simple, I don't think.  I probably need some queueing system.

Load should be similar between the four cores.

Comment: depending on the situation, I would look at creating a "pool" of your own so you have greater control over the creation of the workers, and have each worker handle a subset of the possible symbols. This would only really work well if you have a good distribution of symbols, otherwise if one symbol is much more common than others, it may still all fall to one core really...

Comment: I've asked a more specific question, after looking at `pool`s: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504412/how-can-i-execute-a-function-on-a-cpu-core-and-get-a-callback-when-it-has-compl